# training abs every day, several times a day

Tags: strength-training, abdominals, starting-strength

It's all about body fat we all know it that about abs.I have heard much methods but I am curious about "no stop abs workouts". I plan on lots of abs training everyday (and good nutritional food).

**My 5 times per day ab workout plan:**

- Morning 2 sets of 50.
- Evening 3 sets of 50
- Night 2 sets of 30.

If I do this everyday can abs become like rocks and big? I want an answer only to this. I think it "burns" the fat and the frequency so will be done great results. Your opinion will be great to be hear.

Comment: What exercise are you planning on doing? You didn't state that. But in general this won't work. Ab workouts don't burn a lot of calories, so that won't help, and your abs need rest like any other muscle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Everyone wants a six-pack and everyone wants to increase core strength, but should you do abs exercises every day to accomplish that goal? Some of the most frequent questions I get about abs training are – **“Can you work out abs everyday“**, or **“Should I workout abs everyday“?** Conventional wisdom tells you the more abs exercises you do, the better.

The short answer to the first question is yes, you can train your abs every day, but I don’t think you should train your abs every day.

> **Work Out Abs Everyday Issue #1:**

**You don’t need to do abs exercises to get a strong core, or even a six-pack**

One big misconception about exercise is that you need to do abs exercises in order to get a six-pack, or even a stronger core. You can have a very impressive six-pack with a core as strong as steel by focusing on core, compound exercises like front squats with a barbell/dumbbell, dumbbell lunges, or even polymeric push ups to name a few. Another option is using stabilization exercises like an advanced bird dog exercise that works not just your abs, but your balance, lower back, and even arms and shoulders.

> **Work Out Abs Everyday Issue #2:**

**Frequently working abs can lead to posture problems**

Just about everyone I’ve ever consulted, or trained has moderate, to severe posture problems from a sedentary lifestyle. When you have a desk job, or simply sit down in a chair for a few hours, your shoulders tend to rotate forwards so that your body becomes hunched over.

What does doing a bunch of crunches every day do to this pre-existing problem? Well it makes us hunch over even more by forcing our abs muscles to tighten and shorten. Soon you may be looking like the hunchback of notre dame! Stretching and foam rolling can help correct rounded shoulders and improve posture, but working abs every day may only make whatever posture problems you have worse.

> **Work Out Abs Everyday Issue #3:**

**Abs exercises don’t remove belly fat**

The idea that you can remove stubborn body fat from one particular body part could be the most prevalent myth in the fitness industry. Certainly abs belts and abs machines try to promote this idea of “spot reduction”, but doing abs exercise will not burn any more fat off your body. In fact, when someone asks me how to get a six pack, I tell them “don’t do any abs exercises!”. Getting a six-pack requires achieving a low level of body fat that has nothing to do with how many crunches, or abs exercises you do. Your time is much better spent preparing your meals, planning your meals, or focusing on core, compound exercises. Overall, traditional abs exercises like crunches are extremely overrated.

> **Work Out Abs Everyday Issue #4:**

**Working abs every day is inefficient**

Having a six-pack is like the international sign of fitness, but working out abs every day is unnecessary.
Let’s say you spend 10-20 minutes every day doing abs exercises. You could have spent that time doing high intensity interval training, stretching, foam rolling, and a lot of other fitness activities that would likely be A LOT more beneficial to your body and how it looks and feels. Spending 1 hour of your week working on one muscle group that is really a complex web of muscles is not a very good use of your time. My assumption is you are busy and you would rather spend that time hanging out with friends and enjoying your life!

A better approach would be to work out your abs intensely 2-3x per week using circuits to get a great abs workout in much less time, which is what I personally do. While your abs muscles are most likely comprised of resilient type 1 muscle fibers that can take a beating without getting sore, just like training other muscle groups, they tend to respond better to less frequent training. A similar muscle to abs that has type 1 muscle fibers is your calves, yet you don’t see people doing calves exercises every day!

> **Work Out Abs Everyday Issue #5:**

**Working abs every day can lead to muscle imbalances**

Not only can working out abs every day lead to postural problems, but also muscle imbalances. Your abs complex, which is all your abs muscles are comprised of the rectus abdominus, transverse abdominus, internal obliques, and external obliques. If you do standard crunches 7 days a week for 300 reps, your rectus abdominus muscle (the six-pack muscle) is likely to get trained much more intensely than the other abs muscles. Doing a bunch of crunches does not necessarily translate into a strong abs, or a stable core.

Even worse, if you do get your rectus abdominus too strong relative to your other abs and lower back muscles, you may be more susceptible to injury.

While having nice abs is like the international sign of fitness, there are much more effective ways to work out your abs then to do a bunch of crunches every day!

Source: https://www.builtlean.com

Comment: you make an especially important point about posture. great answer